# How cookies are persisted in webview on IOS

Tags: ios, mobile, cookies, cordova, session-variables

I am currently doing some research and i want to know how cookies are persisted in webview on IOS.

I am planning to write an application where server sends session cookies needs to be available in multiple sessions of webview. I am not sure webview persist these cookies sent by the server for later use.

Please point me to the resources where I can read.

Thanks
Kiranse

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: My app is a web app bundled using phone gap. I am not looking writing any native code. I want to get understanding of how cookies are stored  and retrieved  from webview. Is java script can directly access the cookies stored in webview? like it does in browser.

Comment: As you did not state this I assumed you were writing a native app.  Unfortunately I do not have knowledge of PhoneGap. Maybe you should add a PhoneGap tag to your question.